# How many screws are there in a 5lb box of 3 inch screws?

Tags: screws

About how many screws are in this 5lb box?

[Deck Mate #9 x 3 in. Tan Polymer-Plated Flat-Head Star Wood Screws (5 lb. Pack)](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Deck-Mate-9-x-3-in-Tan-Polymer-Plated-Flat-Head-Star-Wood-Screws-5-lb-Pack-734968/202308663#)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the specs on the page you linked to, "Package Quantity  365".

Answer (score 1):

I weighed 25 of these 3" X 9 composite deck screws and got 5.8 oz.  a box of 5 lbs has 80 oz.  so 80 divided by 5.8 = 13.79 (25 screws). so 25 X 13.79 = about 344 screws. so give or take a few and the previous answer of 365 is likely close.